# Unobtrusive Validation on PostBack Created Class

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm having a little trouble making my request form people proof, so it can only submit valid information and tell the user what is wrong if not.

I want the new properties (a new contact's) created by the controller to be validated as false by unobtrusive JS when the form posts back.

**Important -**
*This is using `BeginCollectionItem` to add and remove `Contact` objects from the property `cmp.contacts (List<Contact>)` dynamically.*

These properties are required, but can be removed from the form. When submitted, the controller checks for them, if not there, it re-adds them to the form.

Due to the properties being just added, they're technically not invalid.

**Update - further investigation**

*However, this does seem strange, as I have made "" as the string values invalid due to requiring a character length of 3 at minimum, set in the model. So in the controller at post back, I check if the list is null, which it is (if the user has deleted it) and create a new list, with a new contact, which then goes through the `ModelState.IsValid` check, which it passes. The contact's properties are string values of "" which should be invalid, but it isn't marking them as invalid until the second post back, why is this?*

**Example story:**

User removes the contact list from the page (you can have 1+ contacts), submits the form, the form fails because it needs at least a contact. The controller creates a new contact and posts the form back to the form. There are contact properties displayed on the page, but because they're newly created, they're not invalid.

If the user tries to submit them again, they're marked as invalid, however I want it to be glaringly obvious what the user needs to fill out.

Can I set them as invalid on post back?

**Partial View with the problem fields:**

```
@model Contact
<div class="editorRow">
    @using (HtmlHelpers.BeginCollectionItem.HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions.BeginCollectionItem(Html, "contacts"))
    {
        <div class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.telephone)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
                <span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.email)
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-d">
                <span>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.type, new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Admin", Value = "Admin" },
                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Peer", Value = "Peer" },
                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Technical", Value = "Technical" }
               })
            <span class="dltBtn">
                <a href="#" class="deleteRow">
                    <img src="~/Images/DeleteRed.png" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;" />
                </a>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var cmp = new Company
            {
                contacts = new List<Contact>
                {
                    new Contact { email = "", name = "", telephone = "", type = "" }
                }
            };
            return View(cmp);
        }

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Company cmp)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.companys.Add(cmp);
                db.SaveChanges();
                EmailSupport.SendEmail(cmp, "Request Form");
                return RedirectToAction("Thankyou", "Home");
            }

            if (cmp.contacts == null)
                cmp.contacts = new List<Contact>
                {
                    new Contact { email = "", name = "", telephone = "" } // this row of properties to show required
                };

            return View(cmp);
        }
```

**Model**

```
[Table("Company")]
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Company name required.")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Telephone required.")]
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Registration Number required.")]
        public string regNumber { get; set; }
        [EnsureOneItem]
        public List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("Contact")]
    public class Contact
    {
        [Key]
        public int contactId { get; set; }
        public int companyId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("companyId")]
        public Company company { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Contact name required.")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Telephone required.")]
        public string telephone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                            @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                            @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                            ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid.")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Contact type required.")]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @StephenMuecke `if(cmp.contacts == null)` doesn't fail, when debugging the collection is null, unsure why or what I'm doing wrong in other areas of my implementation. I've updated the question and will continue to do so with further investigation - I've included the create method from my controller where I pass the `cmp` object to the page. Deleting the only row of `contacts (List<Contact>)` makes `contacts` `null` and not an empty collection on POST.

Comment: Scratch my last comment. `TryUpdateModel()` wont work because the values of the new `Contact` are not in the request. You will need to create a new `ValidationContext`. I'll add an answer shortly

Comment: Thank you - could you also explain why I'm getting `null` returned as the `List<Contact>` when it's instantiated in the controller and passing the object to the form, which then is serialised into html as per my understanding, and sent back on submit - if there's a at least `contacts[0]` contacts will not be `null` when posted.

Comment: You will get `null` in your case because you do not initialize the collection in a constructor for `Contact`. However its typical to do so, so I would recommend also testing if `cmp.contacts` contains any items

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own `ValidationContext` to validate the new `Contact` object, and add the results to `ModelState`

```
if (cmp.contacts == null || !cmp.contacts.Any())
{
  var newContact = new Contact(); // no need to set the values to empty strings
  cmp.contacts = new List<Contact>{ newContact };

  // validate
  var context = new ValidationContext(newContact);
  var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
  Validator.TryValidateObject(newContact, context, results);

  // add errors to ModelState
  foreach(var result in results)
  {
    var propertyName = string.Format("contacts[0].{0}", result.MemberNames.First());
    ModelState.AddModelError(propertyName, result.ErrorMessage);
  }

  return View(cmp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, trying it now, didn't work first time. As for `cmp.contacts`, it does contain contact objects if there are any in the collection, else it's `null`. Just a side note, I don't have any error messages, I'm using this purely to highlight in red, the boxes that require validation.
Still doing the same of only validating the added Contact rows in contacts on the page, if they're there on post.

Comment: If your having problems, let me know and I'll create a DotNetFiddle for you (tested on my machine and works fine) but you will still need to add the `ModelState` errors even if you don't display them

Comment: Just investigating the method you're using in your answer. Getting weird SO errors... If you could that would be very helpful. I'm not using `Html.ValidationMessageFor` as I don't want messages, just want the textbox red border but with the model specified data-annotation validation. Sure you know already due to previous qs, this is using BeginCollectionItem.

Comment: Oh, I forgot your previous questions. That is likely to make a difference (match up errors). I'm not using `BeginCollectionItem` so I can't test it, but let me think about it

Comment: Sorry! Should have mentioned that, I'll update the Q, so when removing the last item in the collection, using the AJAX delete it then won't validate the new elements added when the model returns false (at least one contact is required) so posts back with a newly created `List<Contact>{new Contact();}` - if you need more code then let me know, thanks for your help.

Comment: See edit (inside the `foreach` loop). Its not ideal because it hard codes the property name prefix but should work.

Comment: Unfortunately not - I've updated the question. Where you've specified the index of `contacts[0]` - this could almost be anything, will that work even if it's `contacts[622c798a-d9fc-42f7-b459-a34aea74bade].name` (that's what the one I just tested was). Something akin to jQuery's `name*="whatever"` and it'll find everything with `whatever` in it.

Comment: When debugging, `results` is finding the correct properties and recognising that they're invalid (yay), the `results count=4` which is certainly a big step in the right direction, it's just irritating that they're not being assigned the class `input-validation-erorr` until the post when they're on the page.

Comment: Aren't you over complicating this. Why not just disable the 'delete' button in the if there is only one item left to delete? (you still might check for `null` or `Count = 0` and then just add a general error message to protect against a malicious user)

Comment: Yes, that's my last resort - tried to do it and couldn't and wanted to see if it could be, oddly difficult it seems. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: However if I have multiple partials with this list problem, that's a lot of jQuery to check each one.

Comment: Should only be a a couple of lines of code if your containers have class names

Comment: Yeah it's simple but now I'm intrigued as how to do it, the way I was initially trying - will chuck a bounty up when SO allows to see if it can be done - sure it can, (almost) anything is possible with code.

Comment: I suspect you want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8hnwa8a/) - click the 'delete' buttons to remove items and note how if there is only one left, it cannot be removed

Comment: Quite nice, like how it doesn't matter which ones you delete so long as there's one. In my answer the first one doesn't allow deletion as one row is created and displayed on page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValidateModel()` or `TryValidateModel()` as bellow

```
  if (cmp.contacts == null)
cmp.contacts = new List<Contact>{
                new Contact { email = "", name = "", telephone = "" }
            };
  foreach(Contact cont  in cmp.contacts){
          if(!TryValidateModel(cont)){
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "An Invalid Contact Were Found!");
 //       return View(cmp); or
 return View("InvalidContact",cont);
     //you need to create a view nammed InvalidContact to provide more validation error messages
           }
  }
```

InvalidContact.cshtml

```
              @model  proj.Models.Contact

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                 <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="input-group"> 
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.telephone , new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "telephone " })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.telephone )
                        </div>
                    </div>...
```

Comment: Thank you I'll test that, although adding more pages isn't ideal, don't know how that'll work, only highlighting the box red - is there no way to add the CSS class to the object properties from the back end? I also tried switching my controller around to `if(ModelState.IsValid)` is behind the `if(null)` but that didn't validate them either.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean dear @PurpleSmurph is that a xy problem? maybe! please consider accepting the answer if it helped...

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, is it not possible to add a css class through the controller to an object (contact, in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I tried and failed to get the result I wanted, validation on post back, but turned out to be overly complicated.

This is better (far more simple) and more relevant to more people's problems I'd imagine - thanks to discussion with and suggestion from Stephen.

A simple bit of jQuery to remove the delete button if the length is only 1.

```
var conLen = $('#editorRowsContact .editorRow').length;
            if (conLen == 1) {
                $('#editorRowsContact .editorRow .deleteRow').remove();
            }
```